# Jersey REST 404 error when there's no path

Tags: rest, jersey

I've got a set of RESTful webservices I've developed, and I'm trying to deal with errors for users in a useful way.

I ran into a situation where I mis-coded the URL for an account resource, and got a 404 error.  I expected an error because there were no @Path annotations in the server that would have responded. But since I got a 404, I reported to the user that their account number was not found.

I guess from a purely RESTful standpoint, 404 "makes sense" because there was no "resource" at /server/foo/123450 (when the correct path to the resource is /server/bar/123450). But /server/thisPathHasNoHopeOfExisting/123450 also responds 404.

/server/bar/000000 where account number 00000 doesn't exist responds 404.

How can I tell my user the right thing? (that /server/thisPathHasNoHopeOfExisting/xxxxxx is a true server error, a 500-series, because the server will NEVER answer to that) -- is there a way to make my Jersey services a bit LESS REST-pedantic?

Answer (score 0):

`How can I tell my user the right thing?`

404 *is* the right thing.

`(that /server/thisPathHasNoHopeOfExisting/xxxxxx is a true server error`

What do you mean? Why is it a server error? The client is the one who asked for it, no? If you're creating a "real" REST interface then you are using hypermedia as the engine of application state - the client would never think of /server/thisPathHasNoHopeOfExisting/ because you haven't told them about it.

In Jersey/JAX-RS, you can use UriBuilder to build URIs - and you should. Then there is no 'mis-code the URI'.

You may be able to use the [precedence](http://www.j2eeprogrammer.com/2010/11/jax-rs-path-precedence-rules.html) rules of JAX-RS to create some sort of catch-all page, but I'm not sure that will be very effective. I mean, how can you distinguish between a resource you meant to exist but may not (e.g. an account that doesn't exist) and a resource you don't intend to exist? Your problem stems from an error of omission, therefore any solution you could contrive would also inherit such possible errors. Use UriBuilder.